# How to change HTML tag content in Java?

Tags: java, html, tags, jtidy

How can I change HTML content of tag in Java? For example:

before:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>text<div>**text**</div>text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

after:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>text<div>**new text**</div>text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried JTidy, but it doesn't support `getTextContent`. Is there any other solution?

---

Thanks, I want parse no well-formed HTML. I tried TagSoup, but when I have this code:

```
<body>
sometext <div>text</div>
</body>
```

and I want change "sometext" to "someAnotherText," and when I use `{bodyNode}.getTextContent()` it gives me: "sometext text"; when I use `setTextContet("someAnotherText"+{bodyNode}.getTextContent())`, and serialize these structure, the result is `<body>someAnotherText sometext text</body>`, without `<div>` tags. This is a problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are absolutely sure that the HTML will be valid and well formed, I'd strongly recommend to use an HTML parser, something like [TagSoup](http://www.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html), [NekoHTML](http://www.apache.org/~andyc/neko/doc/html/), [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), etc, the two first being especially powerful to parse any kind of crap :)

For example, with [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) (because the implementation is very easy), using a [visitor](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/visitors/package-summary.html), provide your own [`NodeVisitor`](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/visitors/NodeVisitor.html):

```
public class MyNodeVisitor extends NodeVisitor {
    public MyNodeVisitor() {
    }

    public void visitStringNode (Text string)
    {
        if (string.getText().equals("**text**")) {
            string.setText("**new text**");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, create a [`Parser`](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Parser.html), parse the HTML string and visit the returned node list:

```
Parser parser = new Parser(htmlString);
NodeList nl = parser.parse(null);
nl.visitAllNodesWith(new MyNodeVisitor());
System.out.println(nl.toHtml());
```

This is just one way to implement this, pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that your HTML is a well-formed XML (if it is not then you may use JTidy to tidify it), you can parse it using DOM or SAX parser. DOM is probably easier if your document is not huge.

Something like this will do the trick if your text is the only child of a node with id="id":

```
Document d = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
Element e = d.getElementById("id");
Node text = e.getFirstChild();
text.setNodeValue(process(text.getNodeValue());
```

You may save d afterwards to a file.

Comment: i need more clarification e.getFirstChild(); returns Node,then how can you declare as Element "Element text = e.getFirstChild();"...please clarify me @Dmitry...thanks

Comment: setNodeValue and getNodeValue are defined in Node.Thanks for drawing attention to the return type.

Comment: But you did not define `process(..)` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of Open source Java HTML parsers listed [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers).

I'm not sure what's most commonly used, but [this one](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) (just called HTML parser) will probably do what you want. It has functions to modify your tree and write it back out.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have a HTML document that you want to extract data from. You know generally the structure of the HTML document.

There are several parser libraries but the best one is [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) ,you can use the DOM methods to navigate your document and update values.In your case you need to read your file and use the attribute setter methods.

**Sample XHTML file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="content">Hello World</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Java code :**

```
     File input = new File("D:\\Projects\\Odata Project\\Odata\\src\\web\\html\\inscription_template.xhtml");
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input,null);
            org.jsoup.nodes.Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
            System.out.println(content.text("Hi How are you ?"));
            System.out.println(content.text());
            System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output after execution:**

```
<p id="content">Hi How are you ?</p>
Hi How are you ?
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
--><!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head> 
  <title>Example</title> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <p id="content">Hi How are you ?</p>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Menai, I have an html page with links. It has urls with tags rel="noopener noreferrer". These urls does not open on onClick event. Can you tell what how to solve this problem?